# Velocity driven Poiseuille flow using the incompressible lattice Boltzmann method

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, boundary-conditions, flow, lattice-model

My goal here is to develop a Poiseuille flow in a channel, using constant pressure and zero velocity as initial conditions. From what I have read, people seem to be mostly using pressure-driven, or force-driven Poiseuille flows. However, I wanted to use prescribed velocity at inlet (left boundary), and, following what I understood, I am using prescribed pressure at outlet (right boundary), both using Zou-He boundary conditions. Hence, I set the fluid density, $\rho$, and the $Y$ component of the velocity, $u_y$ at the outlet, and computed $u_x$ as well as the missing distributions accordingly.

However, what I observe is a higher final velocity at the outlet, as shown below (outlet density set to 1).

[image]

Is the free-pressure Zou-He boundary condition not suited in this case? My outlet condition is possibly wrong, although I verified it numerous times. Regarding the rest of the code, it gave convincing results on the driven cavity problem, with good accuracy compared to the reference literature results.

Thanks in advance for your insight!

Comment: What does the plot show? The horizontal velocity component or its magnitude?
So your initial conditions are $\rho, u_x, u_y = \{1, 0, 0\}$, and your boundary conditions at the inlet something like $u_x(y), u_y \approx \{0.05, 0\}$ where you vary $u_x$ over $y$ to obtain a Poiseuille profile and at the outlet $\rho, u_y = \{1, 0\}$? How precisely do you obtain the simulation viscosity? And finally in which order do you apply the Zou/He boundary conditions and the wall?

Comment: In addition to @2b-t's questions, is your channel long enough to fully develop? The Poiseuille flow profile is valid in the infinite axial limit, but obviously it can reach that profile before infinity. If you lengthen your domain, does your solution change?

Comment: @2b-t Thanks for answering. 
- The plot shows the modulus of velocity
- The initial condition is (rho, ux, uy) = (1, 0, 0), and the inlet velocity is set with the exact solution of a Poiseuille. At the outlet, I set (rho, uy) = (1, 0) and deduce ux using classical Zou-He method
- I apply the boundary conditions bottom/left/right/top + bottom-left/top-left/bottom-right/top-right corners. The B.C. are applied after macroscopic fields computation and before computing equilibrium
- Could you elaborate on the viscosity question ? I set u_lbm = 0.05 for the Mach restriction and deduce the rest

Comment: @tpg2114 when I lengthen the channel, things get worse. I may be wrong, but as I use the exact solution of the Poiseuille as input, I am not sure its length should have an impact on the solution ?

Comment: @Scrimbibete I mean that your simulation needs a viscosity and so does your Hagen-Poiseuille profile. How do you determine it? Feel also free to add a link to your implementation, I will have a look at it.

Comment: @2b-t I set Re_lbm, u_lbm and L_lbm, and then deduce the other parameters, including : 

nu_lbm = u_lbm*L_lbm/Re_lbm
tau_lbm = 0.5 + 3*nu_lbm

Does that look correct ? In this case, Re_lbm = 10, u_lbm = 0.05 and L_lbm = 500, so nu_lbm is 2.5

Comment: @Scrimbibete The reason for using periodic boundary conditions with a corresponding pressure drop or an equivalent driving force is that the profile emerges naturally over time without imposing a certain analytic velocity profile at the inlet. It has been some time since I have experimented with them but as far as I remember force-driven periodic flows generally have artifacts near the walls as you would have to account for the presence of the force near the boundary.

Comment: @Scrimbibete **Pressure-drop periodic boundaries** such as **Zhang/Kwok** https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.73.047702 and **Kim/Pitsch** https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2780194 are pretty simple to implement and worked fine for me.

Comment: @Scrimbibete $L = 500$ sounds like you have taken the domain length for calculating the viscosity but generally for flow through a tube the characteristic length is the diameter $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if you incorrectly set the **characteristic length** to the length of the tube $L$ and not its **diameter $D$**. What parameter should be chosen as the characteristic length depends on the problem of interest. It is to some degree arbitrary as long as it reflects the physical behaviour. Clearly the domain length $L$ should not influence the solution but instead only the thickness of the tube, characterised either by the diameter $D = 2 R$ or the radius $R$.

---

**Why did this happen?**

For laminar, steady, fully developed flow in a pipe one can find the analytical velocity profile ([Hagen-Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation))

$$u(r)  = \frac{\Delta p (R^2 - r^2)}{4 \mu L} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

with the maximum velocity along the center-line of the tube

$$u_{max} = \frac{\Delta p R^2}{4 \mu L} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

and the average velocity

$$\overline{u} = \frac{\Delta p R^2}{8 \mu L} = \frac{u_{max}}{2}. \tag{3}\label{3}$$

The Reynolds number may be introduced with respect to the average velocity $\overline{u}$ and the characteristic length $D = 2 R$

$$Re = \frac{2 R \rho \overline{u}}{\mu} = \frac{2 R \overline{u}}{\nu} = \frac{D \overline{u}}{\nu}. \tag{4}\label{4}$$

The velocity profile given by equation \eqref{1} is a parabola that can be also expressed as

$$u(r) = \frac{2 \overline{u}}{R^2} (R^2 - r^2) = \frac{u_{max}}{R^2} (R^2 - r^2): \tag{5}\label{5}$$

The velocity at the center-line $r=0$ it will be maximum $u_{max}$ and at the walls it will be zero.

As you can now see, if you wrongly choose $L = c  D >> D$ as the characteristic length while imposing the velocity profile according to equation \eqref{5}, the initial velocity profile (set at the inlet boundary) will not be the one that would actually develop in a flow with the chosen Reynolds number. Instead the Reynolds number of the developed flow will be $c$ times higher! As a consequence the velocity profile on the left visually corresponds to a lower Reynolds number than the developed profile on the right.

**How to set-up the simulation correctly**

Simply use the definition of the Reynolds number with the characteristic diameter $D_{lb}$ and not the tube length $L_{lb}$ to set the viscosity:

From the definition of the Reynolds number in lattice-Boltzmann ($lb$) units

$$Re = \frac{D_{lb} \overline{u}_{lb}}{\nu_{lb}} $$

one can determine the simulation viscosity $\nu_{lb}$

$$\nu_{lb} = \frac{D_{lb} \overline{u}_{lb}}{Re} $$

and thus enforce a certain kinetic relaxation time $\tau_{lb}$

$$ \tau_{lb} = \frac{\nu_{lb}}{c_{S_{lb}}^2} + \frac{\Delta t_{lb}}{2}$$

which for most classic LBM schemes with $\Delta x_{lb} = \Delta t_{lb} = 1$ and a lattice speed of sound of $c_{S_{lb}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ takes the form

$$ \tau_{lb} = \frac{6 \nu_{lb} + 1}{2}.$$

---

**More appropriate: Pressure-drop periodic boundaries**

Imposing the developed analytical profile is somehow of limited usage. It is basically just a unit test that the solver works correctly as it should preserve the solution given as the boundary condition. Pressure-drop boundaries on the other hand have the advantage that you can control the simulation just using a pressure drop, the developed profile emerges naturally over time.

If you are interested in implementing pressure-driven flow, I would recommend you either the comparably simple method by [Zhang/Kwok](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.73.047702) (but it also rescales the non-equilibrium distribution) or the more sophisticated approach by [Kim/Pitsch](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2780194). I implemented them myself on $D2Q9$- and $D3Q19$-lattices and may be able to answer your questions. As far as I can remember, pressure-driven flows where a forcing term is supposed to mimic the pressure drop suffer from artifacts near the walls in combination with simple bounce-back no-slip walls as such a combination does not account for the impact of the forcing term at the wall.

Comment: That is a very detailed answer, thank you a lot for that. I have taken into account your advices on the proper simulation set-up, but I still experience problems.
What seems to generate this large velocity on the outlet of the domain is to explicitely set the outlet density to 1. When I don't do it, things get much better (although not perfect).
My original intent was to make the final code public, so I will switch it to public now anyway, if you feel like giving it a look, I will be having some free time in the coming weeks anyway... https://github.com/jviquerat/lbm

Comment: @Scrimbibete As the entire Italian territory is on quarantine I have lots of time as well the up-coming weeks. ;) I will have a look at your code later today!

Comment: That's nice of you, feel free to open issues/request PRs :)

Comment: @Scrimbibete I just had a quick glance at your code. Is there a reason you used $\overline{u}_{you} = \frac{2}{3} u$ instead of $\overline{u}_{me} = \frac{1}{2} u$ as suggested in my post? If I enforce the pressure at the outlet, use my $\overline{u}_{me}$ and increase the time step then the results look fine to me. Be aware that you need a lot of time steps in order to reach the steady solution as your initial condition is quite unphysical and will create shock wave perturbations that will be reflected by the outlet pressure boundary and thus the first few time steps look very unphysical.

Comment: @Scrimbibete If you want to improve this behaviour you could try **Latt's regulararised boundary conditions** that try to estimate the non-equilibrium distribution $f^{(neq)}$ by $f^{(1)}$ from the Chapman-Enskog expansion in combination with non-equilibrium bounce-back https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.77.056703 or implement the more stable **Guo's extrapolation boundaries** https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1009-1963/11/4/310/meta. They both improve pressure wave reflection behaviour and stability for higher Reynolds numbers significantly as well.

Comment: @Scrimbibete Futhermore have you tried **Numba** for speeding up your loops https://numba.pydata.org? Python is the fastest if used wih libraries such as vectorised Numpy or pre-compiled Numba. Numpy has a completely different syntax but Numba basically only pre-compiles loop-based Python code to C++ and should be significantly faster without changing your syntax - you only will have to introduce decorators above each function you want to pre-compile.

Comment: @Scrimbibete I have written a LBM code in C++ (see my hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58472929/9938686)) some time ago and multithreaded it with OpenMP. Introducing loop blocking I was able to update around 300 million lattice cells per second (Mlups) with a D2Q9 lattice on a six-core processor, meaning I could calculate around 10 000 time steps in a single second. I doubt Pyhon can come close to this performance but I guess you could push it to somewhere around 100 Mlups which makes simulation very convenient.

Comment: @Scrimbibete In case you need some literature on the topic I can recommend you the [book by Timm Krüger et alii](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319446479). Furthermore you can find some notes and hints on the topic in my [master's thesis](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ps8xzwnjbgb24qu/AADQv5I2e2zxb13PjWp1PIKGa?dl=0). If you plan on doing a 3D simulation I can recommend you the [AA-pattern](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/people/pbailey/Accelerating_GPU_LBM.pdf), a smart change in the algorithm that allows you to only load vaues from memory once and thus decreases the required memory bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for all the insights. I just realized that I had commented a line for testing, which was imposing the outlet density to 1 in the Zou-He condition.
The situation is :
- If I do not set explicitely rho(outlet) = 1, I obtain an almost-correct poiseuille, but not perfect (off by a few percent), and it does not converge when refining
- If I do set explicitely rho(outlet) = 1, I obtain what is shown in the original question
See lattice_utils.py line 332, if you ever have some time to look at it.

It is possible that I did not understand Zou-He procedure correctly.

Comment: I will be looking at all your suggestions. The context of this code is that I need a small, manageable 2D code able to solve simple flows (typically, moderate reynolds flows around random shapes) for research. I tried Fenics but did not appreciate it. I have an in-house FEM code, but cannot share it easily for confidentiality purposes. Thus the LBM code

Your master's thesis seems to be of excellent quality, it is a shame I did not find it before, while I was looking for an LBM introduction.

Comment: Update : after some corrections, I am getting an accurate final result, wether I start from a fully initialized field, or only a velocity input on the left. However, in the second case, I experience a lot of "bouncing" through the domain, before things stabilize. I suppose working on the initialization step and on the outlet B.C., as you suggested, will help improve the situation.

Comment: @Scrimbibete Glad it works now! Another thing I forgot to mention is that the Zou-He boundaries in your implementation might be slightly wrong: I think they are not identical to the ones I use and the ones in the original paper even though they are mathematically very similar: You use the non-equilibrium bounce-back explicitly  while I use the original implementation which uses only the velocity instead (page 46 of my thesis). In your implementation you need the equilibrium function but I think you calculate it before streaming and collision so it is actually not the current $f^{(eq)}$.

Comment: @Scrimbibete Furthermore is there any particular reason why you calculate Macro before the boundary conditions? I would calculate it afterwards, right before calculating the equilibrium distribution as this should have a slight impact on the collision at the boundaries (Zou/He collide and stream like normal cells). Both of those things should not be visible in a steady-state flow but I think they would lead to slight errors in time-dependent flows.

Comment: @Scrimbibete Lattice-Boltzmannn codes are pretty easy to write, even for complex geometries, they are virtually mesh-less but in my opinion there are three big drawbacks: Firstly they may be seem easy to implement but it is quite hard to implement them efficiently and sometimes finding errors can be a nightmare as you have to work on level of the distributions. Sometimes you will be asking yourself is this my fault/did I make mistakes implementing it, is this inherent to LBM or an effect of the boundary conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105801/discussion-between-2b-t-and-scrimbibete).